# Visual Studio Setup when first viewing a page

Tags: visual-studio, installation, code-folding

Is there a way to setup visual studio 2008 to automatically collapse regions/functions/methods when the code behind is first opened?

Comment: i want see solution to visual studio 2010 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 this seems to auto collapse regions but not methods, classes, etc:

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Check "Enter Outlining mode when files open".

I use the short-cut Ctrl + M, L to toggle collapsed regions.